# Не подключаются js и css к html на локальном сервере http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Tags: javascript, html, css, сервер

Ловлю 404 при попытке подключить js и css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Imidge Bord</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="js/req.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
```

При попытке просто открыть html(Сервер отключен), все работает. Код выполняется, стили работают. Но как только запускаю сервер , пишет "GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/js/req.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)"

Структура директории такая:

```
mainFolder:
    templates:
        basic_template.html
        index.css
        js(Папка)
          req.js
app.py
+другие файлы
```

Полный путь к js-файлу выглядит так:
/home/user/Python_Projects/mainFolder/templates/js/req.js

Скриншот папки:
[image: Скрин]

config.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__author__ = 'user'


DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY='secret'
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///test.db'
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
```

Comment: Не знаю. А это как? Что-то вроде ./js/req.js? Так пробовал.

Comment: К сожалению, не работает.

Comment: Добавил в тему.

Comment: Выводится html. Файлы .py обрабатывают данные, полученные через html форму.

Comment: js файла там нет. Значит ошибка в пути, знать бы только как её обнаружить.

Comment: нужен код обрабатывающий запросы get

Comment: Если вы про python, то и это не помогло. Даже при наличие кода, обрабатывающего get запросы, js не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась созданием в папке mainFolder, папки static и переносом туда js и css. В html прописал пусть:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/req.js') }}""></script>
```

Теперь все прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1):

> При попытке просто открыть html(Сервер отключен), все работает.

Когда вы открываете `basic_template.html` на одном уровне с ним находится папка `js` со скриптами и у вас все открывается. Но когда вы запрашиваете страницу с сервера, то относительно корня полный путь до скриптов превращается в `templates/js/` и они не находятся.

решение:

исправьте в шаблоне

```
<script src="js/req.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
```

на

```
<script src="/templates/js/req.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/index.css">
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Ошибка "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)". Во всяком случае, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: а можете приложить к вопросу ваш config.py, возможно там какой-то нестандартный роутинг?

Comment: Приложил. Но там вроде ничего такого.